# How can I run a function in another thread until a button is pressed, and then how can I update the web page in that thread without JavaScript?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a website that uses GPIO pins to read and display temperature and humidity. I have the basic functionality, but now I want what happens when you press the start button to run in another thread infinitely long, until you press the stop button. After each run the website should be updated. I work without JavaScript, but with flask.

This is what my website looks like. (Please do not pay attention to the If's)

```css
.container 
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.3% 33.3%;
    grid-template-rows: 75px 75px 75px 75px 75px 75px 75px 75px 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
#f1
{
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 5 / 10;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
    grid-template-rows: 75px 75px 75px 75px 75px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.WhiteBackground
{
    background: white;
}
.BlackColor
{
    color: black;
}
.RedBackground
{
    background: red;
}
.WhiteColor
{
    color: white;
}
.BlueBackground
{
    background: blue;
}
.GreenBackground
{
    background: green;
}
.button {
    font: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #333333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333333;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
  }
.fsize 
{ 
    font-size: 25px;
}
.cbtn 
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
#e6
{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
}
#e7
{
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
}
#e8
{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    /*grid-row: 9 / 10;*/
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
}
#h1Titel
{
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 43px;
}
#pTemperatur
{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#pLuftfeuchtigkeit
{
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#AusgabeTemp
{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#AusgabeLuft
{
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    line-height: 70px;
}
#buttonStart
{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
}
#buttonStop
{
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
}
#pErklaerung1
{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    /*grid-row: 5 / 6;*/
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#TempGruenMin
{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    /*grid-row: 6 / 7;*/
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 75px;
}
#pUnd1
{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    /*grid-row: 6 / 7;*/
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#TempGruenMax
{
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    /*grid-row: 6 / 7;*/
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
        height: 75px;
}
#pErklaerung2
{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    /*grid-row: 7 / 8;*/
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#LuftGruenMin
{
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    /*grid-row: 8 / 9;*/
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 75px;
}
#pUnd2
{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    /*grid-row: 8 / 9;*/
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#LuftGruenMax
{
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    /*grid-row: 8 / 9;*/
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 75px;
}
#buttonSpeichern
{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    /*grid-row: 9 / 10;*/
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Temperatur und Luftfeuchtigkeit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="h1Titel" style="font-size:40px">Temperatur und Luftfeuchtigkeit</h1>
            <p id="pTemperatur" style="font-size:25px">Temperatur</p>
            <p id="pLuftfeuchtigkeit" style="font-size:25px">Luftfeuchtigkeit</p>
            {% if   isRunning  == False %}
                <p id="AusgabeTemp" style="font-size:25px" class="WhiteBackground BlackColor">{{ temperature }}°C</p>
            {% elif  isTempBiggerMax  == True %} 
                <p id="AusgabeTemp" style="font-size:25px" class="RedBackground WhiteColor">{{ temperature }}°C</p>
            {% elif  isTempLowerMin  == True %}
                <p id="AusgabeTemp" style="font-size:25px" class="BlueBackground WhiteColor">{{ temperature }}°C</p>
            {% else %}
                <p id="AusgabeTemp" style="font-size:25px" class="GreenBackground WhiteColor">{{ temperature }}°C</p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if  isRunning  == False %}
                <p id="AusgabeLuft" style="font-size:25px" class="WhiteBackground BlackColor">{{ luftfeuchtigkeite }}%</p>
            {% elif  isLuftBiggerMax  == True %}
                <p id="AusgabeLuft" style="font-size:25px" class="RedBackground WhiteColor">{{ luftfeuchtigkeite }}%</p>
            {% elif  isLuftLowerMin  == True %}
                <p id="AusgabeLuft" style="font-size:25px" class="BlueBackground WhiteColor">{{ luftfeuchtigkeite }}%</p>
            {% else %}
                <p id="AusgabeLuft" style="font-size:25px" class="GreenBackground WhiteColor">{{ luftfeuchtigkeite }}%</p>
            {% endif %}
            
            {% if  buttonStart  == 'active' %}
                <span class="cbtn" id="e6" style="font-size:25px">
                    <a href="/start" class="button" id="buttonStart" style="font-size:25px">Start</a>
                </span>
            {% else %}
                <span class="cbtn" id="e6" style="font-size:25px">
                    <a class="button" id="buttonStart" style="font-size:25px" disabled>Start</a>
                </span>
            {% endif %}
            {% if  buttonStop  == 'active' %}
                <span class="cbtn" id="e7" style="font-size:25px">
                    <a href="/stop" class="button" id="buttonStop" style="font-size:25px">Stop</a>
                </span>
            {% else %}
                <span class="cbtn" id="e7" style="font-size:25px">
                    <a class="button" id="buttonStop" style="font-size:25px" disabled>Stop</a>
                </span>
            {% endif %}
            <form id='f1' method="POST">
                <p id="pErklaerung1" style="font-size:25px">Grüner Temperaturen Bereich: zwischen</p>
                <input id="TempGruenMin" name="TempGruenMin" rows="1" value="{{ MinTemp }}">
                <p id="pUnd1" style="font-size:25px">und</p>
                <input id="TempGruenMax" name="TempGruenMax" rows="1" value="{{ MaxTemp }}">
                <p id="pErklaerung2" style="font-size:25px">Grüner Luftfeuchtigkeiten Bereich: zwischen</p>
                <input id="LuftGruenMin" name="LuftGruenMin" rows="1" value="{{ MinHumi }}">
                <p id="pUnd2" style="font-size:25px">und</p>
                <input id="LuftGruenMax" name="LuftGruenMax" rows="1" value="{{ MaxHumi }}">
                <span class="cbtn" id="e8" style="font-size:25px">
                    <input type="submit" href="/speichern" value="Speichern" id="buttonSpeichern" style="font-size:25px">
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Python-File:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#imports

#variables and GPIO-Pins defined

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    #Mainsite

@app.route('/<deviceName>')
def action(deviceName):
    global Threadbeenden
    global DHTSensor
    global Luftfeuchtigkeite
    global minimumGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit
    global minimumGruenerBereichTemperatur
    global maximalGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit
    global maximalGruenerBereichTemperatur
    global Temperature
    global ledBluePin
    global ledBlueStatus
    global ledGreenPin
    global ledGreenStatus
    global ledRedPin
    global ledRedStatus
    global labLuftVordergrundFarbe
    global labTempVordergrundFarbe
    global labLuftHintergrundFarbe
    global labTempHintergrundFarbe
    global templateData
    global isRunning
    global isBiggerMax
    global isLowerMin
    global isLBiggerMax
    global isLLowerMin
    if deviceName == 'start':
        isRunning = True
        buttonStopStatus = ButtonEnabeln()
        buttonStartStatus = ButtonDisabeln()
        Luftfeuchtigkeit, Temperatur = dht.read_retry(DHTSensor, 23)
        Luft = str(Luftfeuchtigkeit)
        Temp = str(Temperatur)
        ledRedStatus, ledBlueStatus, ledGreenStatus, labTempHintergrundFarbe, labTempVordergrundFarbe, labLuftHintergrundFarbe, labLuftVordergrundFarbe, isBiggerMax, isLowerMin, isLBiggerMax, isLLowerMin = Farbe(Temperatur, Luftfeuchtigkeit)
        Luftfeuchtigkeite = Luft
        Temperature = Temp
        templateData = {
            'ledRed' : ledRedStatus,
            'ledBlue' : ledBlueStatus,
            'ledGreen' : ledGreenStatus,
            'buttonStart' : buttonStartStatus,
            'buttonStop' : buttonStopStatus,
            'temperature' : Temperature,
            'luftfeuchtigkeite' : Luftfeuchtigkeite,
            'MinTemp' : minimumGruenerBereichTemperatur,
            'MaxTemp' : maximalGruenerBereichTemperatur,
            'MinHumi' : minimumGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit,
            'MaxHumi' : maximalGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit,
            'isRunning' : isRunning,
            'isTempBiggerMax' : isBiggerMax,
            'isTempLowerMin' : isLowerMin,
            'isLuftBiggerMax' : isLBiggerMax,
            'isLuftLowerMin' : isLLowerMin
        }
        render_template('index.html', title='Home', **templateData)
    if deviceName == 'stop':
        isRunning =  False
        Threadbeenden = True
        ledRedStatus = 0
        ledBlueStatus = 0
        ledGreenStatus = 0
        buttonStartStatus = ButtonEnabeln()
        buttonStopStatus = ButtonDisabeln()
        Temperatur = '--'
        Luftfeuchtigkeit = ''
        labLuftHintergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
        labLuftVordergrundFarbe = 'BLACK'
        labTempHintergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
        labTempVordergrundFarbe = 'BLACK'
        GPIO.output(ledGreenPin, 0)
        GPIO.output(ledBluePin, 0)
        GPIO.output(ledRedPin, 0)

        templateData = {
            'ledRed' : ledRedStatus,
            'ledBlue' : ledBlueStatus,
            'ledGreen' : ledGreenStatus,
            'buttonStart' : buttonStartStatus,
            'buttonStop' : buttonStopStatus,
            'temperature' : Temperature,
            'luftfeuchtigkeite' : Luftfeuchtigkeite,
            'MinTemp' : minimumGruenerBereichTemperatur,
            'MaxTemp' : maximalGruenerBereichTemperatur,
            'MinHumi' : minimumGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit,
            'MaxHumi' : maximalGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit,
            'isRunning' : isRunning,
            'isTempBiggerMax' : isBiggerMax,
            'isTempLowerMin' : isLowerMin,
            'isLuftBiggerMax' : isLBiggerMax,
            'isLuftLowerMin' : isLLowerMin
        }
        return render_template('index.html', title='Home', **templateData)
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', **templateData)

def Farbe(Temperatur, Luftfeuchtigkeit):
    global minimumGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit
    global minimumGruenerBereichTemperatur
    global maximalGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit
    global maximalGruenerBereichTemperatur
    global labLuftHintergrundFarbe
    global labLuftVordergrundFarbe
    global labTempHintergrundFarbe
    global labTempVordergrundFarbe
    global isRunning
    global isBiggerMax
    global isLowerMin
    global isLBiggerMax
    global isLLowerMin
    if Temperatur is not None and Luftfeuchtigkeit is not None:
        print("Hallo")
        if int(float(Temperatur)) < int(minimumGruenerBereichTemperatur):
            labTempHintergrundFarbe = 'BLUE'
            labTempVordergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
            GPIO.output(ledGreenPin, 0)
            ledGreenStatus = 0
            GPIO.output(ledBluePin, 1)
            ledBlueStatus = 1
            GPIO.output(ledRedPin, 0)
            ledRedStatus = 0
            isBiggerMax = False
            isLowerMin = True
        elif (int(float(Temperatur)) >= int(minimumGruenerBereichTemperatur)) and (int(float(Temperatur)) <= int(maximalGruenerBereichTemperatur)):
            labTempHintergrundFarbe = 'GREEN'
            labTempVordergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
            GPIO.output(ledGreenPin, 1)
            ledGreenStatus = 1
            GPIO.output(ledBluePin, 0)
            ledBlueStatus = 0
            GPIO.output(ledRedPin, 0)
            ledRedStatus = 0
            isBiggerMax = False
            isLowerMin = False
        else:
            labTempHintergrundFarbe = 'RED'
            labTempVordergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
            GPIO.output(ledGreenPin, 0)
            ledGreenStatus = 0
            GPIO.output(ledBluePin, 0)
            ledBlueStatus = 0
            GPIO.output(ledRedPin, 1)
            ledRedStatus = 1
            isBiggerMax = True
            isLowerMin = False

        if int(float(Luftfeuchtigkeit)) < int(minimumGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit):
            labLuftHintergrundFarbe = 'BLUE'
            labLuftVordergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
            isLBiggerMax = False
            isLLowerMin = True
        elif (int(float(Luftfeuchtigkeit)) >= int(minimumGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit)) and (int(float(Luftfeuchtigkeit)) <= int(maximalGruenerBereichLuftfeuchtigkeit)):
            labLuftHintergrundFarbe = 'GREEN'
            labLuftVordergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
            isLBiggerMax = False
            isLLowerMin = False
        else:
            labLuftHintergrundFarbe = 'RED'
            labLuftVordergrundFarbe = 'WHITE'
            isLBiggerMax = True
            isLLowerMin = False
    return ledRedStatus, ledBlueStatus, ledGreenStatus, labTempHintergrundFarbe, labTempVordergrundFarbe, labLuftHintergrundFarbe, labLuftVordergrundFarbe, isBiggerMax, isLowerMin, isLBiggerMax, isLLowerMin

def ButtonEnabeln():
    return 'active'

def ButtonDisabeln():
    return 'disable'

@app.route('/<a>', methods=['POST'])
def speichern(a):
    #savebutton clicked event  


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def save():
    #savebutton clicked event
```

Comment: Please provide and **minimal**, complete, reproducible example.

Comment: What?? I didn't understood what you mean

Comment: You have provided so much code that most folks will not want to read through all of it.  Also, you have asked a very broad open-ended question.  What have to tried to make the flask server handle threads?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't get mistakes. I just don't know how it works. I already got answers on the internet, but with JavaScript. I don't want to use JavaScript. I try to reduce the python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do client side processing with python via jinja. The template is processed server side and rendered to the client browser. You would need to use JavaScript.

EDIT: You *could* make an AJAX request (via JavaScript) back to the server to do the processing, then update the client.